# ChartJS tooltip issue

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js, tooltip

Tooltip shows on the legend and label, how to hide it.

[image]

Looking for suggestions.

This results in the following code (press button "Run code snippet" below).

````html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
<title>Bar Chart</title>
<script src="https://www.chartjs.org/dist/2.9.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.chartjs.org/samples/master/utils.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container" style="width: 75%;">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
<script>
    var color = Chart.helpers.color;
    var barChartData = {
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Dataset 1',
            backgroundColor: 'green',
            borderColor: 'green',
            borderWidth: 1,
            data: [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7500]
        }, {
            label: 'Dataset 2',
            type: 'line',
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            borderColor: 'red',
            borderWidth: 2,
            data: [1060, 2110, 3098, 4010, 4020, 5010, 3030, ]
        }]
    };
    window.onload = function() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
        window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: barChartData,
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                legend: {
                    position: 'bottom',
                },
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Chart.js Bar Chart'
                }
            }
        });
    };
</script>
</body>

</html>

```
````

Comment: you want hide tooltip at all?

Comment: Hi, No, just I want to hide the tooltip on the label. If you see the image  when hover over on the label tooltip shows so just need to hide that one.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this (not showing tooltip on label hover) :

````html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
<title>Bar Chart</title>
<script src="https://www.chartjs.org/dist/2.9.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.chartjs.org/samples/master/utils.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container" style="width: 75%;">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
<script>
    var color = Chart.helpers.color;
    var barChartData = {
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Dataset 1',
            tooltip:false,
            backgroundColor: 'green',
            borderColor: 'green',
            borderWidth: 1,
            
            data: [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7500]
        }, {
            label: 'Dataset 2',
            type: 'line',
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            borderColor: 'red',
            borderWidth: 2,
            data: [1060, 2110, 3098, 4010, 4020, 5010, 3030, ]
        }]
     
};
    window.onload = function() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
        window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: barChartData,
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                legend: {
                    position: 'bottom',
                },
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Chart.js Bar Chart'
                }, tooltips: {
         intersect : false,
       filter: function (tooltipItem) {
            return tooltipItem.datasetIndex === 1;
        }
    }
            }
        });
    };
</script>
</body>

</html>

```
````

Comment: Hi, It still shows the tooltip on label, please can you check it again.. Thanks

Comment: @user12363638 i will greateful to set my answer correct if you are satisfied about it :)

Comment: Hi, I need to show the tooltip on line and bar but when hove over on the label it shows the tooltip just to hide that one.

Comment: @user12363638 please check it now :)

Comment: If I use the version 2.5.0, problem solves but I need to use v2.9.2 or 3.

Comment: If you hover over on the legend , tooltip shows. I don't understand this part.

Comment: because it is a part of bar , not just a label